# Is there a way to combine columns from cli output?

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I want to get memorydb endpoint URL in the format (address:port). When I run the aws cli command `aws memorydb describe-clusters --cluster-name xxx --query 'Clusters[0].ClusterEndpoint' --output text`, I get the output as (address  port).

I want to get it in the format (address:port). Is there a command i can use to add ':' to combine address and port number.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible to achieve this by using simple `sed`, something like this:

```
aws memorydb describe-clusters --cluster-name abctest --query 'Clusters[0].ClusterEndpoint' --output text | sed 's/\t/:/g'

clustercfg.abctest.xxxx.memorydb.region-x-1.amazonaws.com:6379
```

Tested with aws cli. The describe-clusters output contains tab, not a single space. See if this works for you.

Comment: Perhaps `tr` would be simpler than `sed`. Both approaches would replace all spaces by colons, i.e. `address    port` would become `address::::port`. This is likely not a problem here, because from what I see, there is only a single space present.

Comment: Actually it contains tab and not one/multiple spaces. Edited the answer after testing with actual aws cli.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have set your variable to the string which you posted, i.e.

```
x='(address port)'
```

you can calculate using parameter expansion

```
y=${x/ /:}
```

which substitutes the first space by a colon and gives you on `y` the value `(address:port)`.

Comment: May be worth mentioning you are using a bash *parameter expansion* (with substring replacement) to replace the first occurrence of a space with a colon. That way if the OP wants to look further into the subject, they have the proper terminology to use. (that said, this is an excellent approach)